# nginx is not able to connect to uWSGI after 100 socket connections

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

We are using Docker for a Flask application and there is an nginx-uwsgi image [tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask) which we are using.

The Docker image works fine for most of the application, but one of the deployments gives an error after some times.

The actual error is

```
2020/10/21 18:17:49 [error] 12#12: *142201 connect() to unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.255.0.212, server: , request: "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.0", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock:"
```

The error says there is an issue with a `uwsgi` socket. When I check the connection to uWSGI sockets, I get a `101` connection with a `CONNECTING` label.

```
root@eaf23a900022:/app# netstat -nap | grep uwsgi | grep CONNECTING | wc -l
101
root@eaf23a900022:/app# netstat -nap | grep uwsgi | grep CONNECTING
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        -                    /tmp/uwsgi.sock
```

From this, it appears, `nginx` makes a connection to `uwsgi` and then it’s not able to release it.

There are other Flask applications running in the same image. I check the how many `CONNECTING` sockets I get, but the other containers return `ZERO`.

```
root@466d15de99c7:/app# ps aux | grep uwsgi
root         10  0.3  0.2 298340 44636 ?        Sl   Oct17  11:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
root         36  0.0  0.2 298340 42776 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
root         37  0.0  0.2 298340 43316 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
root        320  0.0  0.0  12848   960 pts/0    S+   17:23   0:00 grep uwsgi
root@466d15de99c7:/app# kill -9 10 36 37
root@466d15de99c7:/app# ps aux | grep uwsgi
root        321 43.0  0.3 222368 49872 ?        D    17:24   0:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
root        325  0.0  0.0  12848   960 pts/0    S+   17:24   0:00 grep uwsgi
root@466d15de99c7:/app# ps aux | grep uwsgi
root        321 23.5  0.3 298476 52380 ?        Sl   17:24   0:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
root        327  0.0  0.2 298476 43728 ?        S    17:24   0:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
root        328  0.0  0.2 298476 43728 ?        S    17:24   0:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
root        330  0.0  0.0  12848   960 pts/0    S+   17:24   0:00 grep uwsgi
root@466d15de99c7:/app# netstat -nap | grep uwsgi | grep CONNECTING | wc -l
0
```

There are some `NGINX` tuning parameter sets in this. The `printenv` output is below.

```
[nile2691@983195-dfw301web02 ~]$ docker exec -it b2cff9ac29a2 printenv
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=b2cff9ac29a2
TERM=xterm
API_PASS=XXXXX
API_USER=XXXX
APP_ENVIRONMENT=bleeding
BCAPI_URL=https://example.com
BSAPI_APP=RpcApi
BSAPI_DB_NAME=RPC_Bleeding
BSAPI_DB_URI=mongodb://username:mongodb.instance:26200/database?ssl=true
BSAPI_ES_LOGGING=True
BSAPI_REDIS_URI=redis://:password@redis.instance:6379/0
BSNOTIFY_ENV=staging
CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://username:password@rabbit.instance/vhostg
NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS=2048
NGINX_WORKER_OPEN_FILES= 2048
NGINX_WORKER_PROCESSES=8
LANG=C.UTF-8
GPG_KEY=0D96DF4D4110E5C43FBFB17F2D347EA6AA65421D
PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.4
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=19.2.1
PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/404c9418e33c5031b1a9ab623168b3e8a2ed8c88/get-pip.py
PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=56bb63d3cf54e7444351256f72a60f575f6d8c7f1faacffae33167afc8e7609d
NGINX_VERSION=1.15.8-1~stretch
NJS_VERSION=1.15.8.0.2.7-1~stretch
UWSGI_INI=/app/uwsgi.ini
UWSGI_CHEAPER=2
UWSGI_PROCESSES=16
NGINX_MAX_UPLOAD=0
LISTEN_PORT=80
STATIC_URL=/static
STATIC_PATH=/app/static
STATIC_INDEX=0
PYTHONPATH=/app
HOME=/root
```

We are trying to understand why socket connection is stuck in `CONNECTING` and not clear after a request fulfill.

What makes this socket queue to reach to `101` counts?

When it reaches `100+`, it's starting giving socket errors.

We can increase the queue size, but we are sure it will be full again.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your code why the uWSGI doesn't release the socket.

Before that, you can add **max-requests = 100** in your uWSGI configuration file that makes the process reload after handling 100 requests.